# Water Hammer from Upstairs Toilet

Tags: plumbing, water, toilet, plumbing-fixture, water-hammer

After my upstairs toilet is flushed and the bowl fully refills, it sounds like a water hammer.

Here's a video of the noise. At 4 seconds, when the bowl has refilled, you hear the noise:

[url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaqWCjywjUo"]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaqWCjywjUo[/url]

Please note I've been in this house for years, no work was recently done to this toilet or any plumbing in my home recently, and have never had this issue before with this or any toilet.

What can be done to correct this? Someone mentioned to me to buy a water hammer arrestor.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for the help, everyone. I checked my water pressure and it was fine. I then purchased and installed a new fill valve, and the noise completely stopped!

Comment: User89412 you chose the same option J.raefield had suggested the up vote should have been to him.

Comment: you should leave a comment on the other answer and "accept it"

Answer (score 5):

That's not water hammer, or it's very little at best. That sounds more like the fact that your fill valve is getting a little old and is banging shut harder than it used to. I would just leave it, but if it bugs you, replace the fill valve. There are newer ones on the market now called "quiet" or even "silent" fill valves. They are a little more money, but you seem like the kind of person that would want that.

http://www.mechanicalcaveman.com/best-toilet-fill-valve-review-flush-system-kit-replacement/